# Error 503 connecting to secure WebSockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, cloudflare

I am trying to establish a websockets connection to a site that uses both Amazon web services and Cloudflare.  Navigating to that page and viewing the traffic with Chrome developer tools shows a ton of traffic, but if I try to open a connection from JS, Java, or wscat I get a 503 error every time:

`$ wscat -c wss://idex.market
error: Unexpected server response: 503`

Here's the same thing using node.js:

```
// test.js:
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://idex.market/');
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

$ node test.js
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Unexpected server response: 503
```

Any ideas?  I suspect it's related to either Cloudflare or AWS.

Answer (score 0):

First, you check `ws.onError()` (I'm not a nodejs developer) and see if there is any errors available on server side. Second, I have had two issues with how cloudflare services handle websocket connections that I'm going to share with you.

One was that some java libraries were not able to open secure connections because their supported cipher-suite were not matching server ones.

Second was that I could not open too many websocket connections (usually more than ~500) because I was using free plan.